# Is there a way to get the set width of the current element in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

Tp center absolutely positioned elements I have to devide the current width in half and set that as the negative left margin value. But I don't want to have to do:

```
#elem {
    width: 75px;
    margin-left: -(75/2)px;
}
```

Since now if I update the width I have to update it in 2 places. Instead is it possible to reference the set width for the current selector in some way in SASS?

Psudo code:

```
#elem {
    width: 75px;
    margin-left: -(this.width/2)px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was going to suggest the same approach as @GEspinha, but if you are going to be doing this on many different elements it might be worthwhile to use a mixin:

```
@mixin absolute-width($width) {
    margin-left: -($width/2);
    width: $width;
}

#elem {
    @include absolute-width(75px);
}

#elem2 {
    @include absolute-width(50px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple and flexible way to do something like this is by creating a variable and use it within the class. **There is still no way to target a specific attribute value of an element in SASS.**

```
$var: 75px;

#elem {
    width: $var;
    margin-left: -($var/2);
}
```